# Identify Account add/remove in Android device

Tags: android, accountmanager

Is there any way (**BroadcastReceiver or something else**) to know when account gets added or removed in Account under settings sections. I have gone through below link:

[Account manager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#addAccount(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler))

Comment: AccountManager.addOnAccountsUpdatedListener()

Comment: @krislarson could you share some piece of code? Anyway thanks a lot.